# Postscript: truncate string with ellipsis?

Tags: string, printing, postscript

Is there a way via PostScript to add a string such that is will be truncated by "..." so as not to exceed a certain width?

I've looking at some old report generation code and would like add this feature.  In the existing reports, values that are too long are visually overwriting other data.

The reason I'm trying to do this at the PS level is that in the existing code I don't see anything that could calculate any kind of accurate width metric.

I've yet to write any Postscript, so maybe this is trivial. (?)

Per comment below: Yes, localization will an issue.  So I guess a user defined "ellipsis" string makes sense.

Here is some example output that shows how strings are currently printed:

```
% Change font style and/or size
/Times-Roman-ISOLatin1 findfont 12 scalefont setfont
219 234 moveto (AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA_) show
```

Can this be modified to ellipsize things?

Comment: find one of the long strings in the postscript and post that along with a few lines of surrounding code, we'll see how feasable it is.

Comment: @george Thank you. Question updated with excerpt from output.

Comment: Redefinee the 'show operator so that it determines the width of the string so far on output, and if it exceeds you limit, stop processing and emit your 'ellipsis' character. This will require some experience of PostScript programming.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can do something like this (replace the char in front of concatstrings with your ellipsis):

```
/concatstrings % (a) (b) -> (ab)  
   { exch dup length    
     2 index length add string    
     dup dup 4 2 roll copy length
     4 -1 roll putinterval
   } bind def  

/ellipsis_show {
   1 dict begin
     /width_t exch def
     {dup stringwidth pop width_t lt {exit} if dup length 1 sub 0 exch getinterval} loop
     (_) concatstrings
     show
    end
}def

% Change font style and/or size
/Times-Roman-ISOLatin1 findfont 12 scalefont setfont
0 0 moveto (foobar barfoo foofoo barbar) 100.0 ellipsis_show
```

concatstrings copied from: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PostScript_FAQ#How_to_concatenate_strings.3F

Comment: nice. note you dont really need concatstrings, just show one after the other.. Also you could 'build' an ellipsis out of three periods and use awidthshow, to avoid portability issues.

Comment: @george Yeah, it looks like this because originally the function only built the string. So the user can use whatever show, outline, or clipping routines they wished.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is 'no'. A longer answer is that, since PostScript is a programming language, you *can* do this, but it will require some knowledge of PostScript, and some work, it certainly is not trivial.

You can redefine the various operators which draw text on the output, there are quite a few; show, ashow, cshow, kshow, xshow, yshow, xyshow, widthshow, awidthshow, and glyphshow. You could define modified versions of these which determine (using stringwidth and the parameters used by the various operators) the width of thefinal  printed text. Probably you would want to calculate this glyph by glyph and terminate with your ellipsis when the value exceeds some threshold. (NB not all fonts will contain an ellipsis glyph, and its encoded position may vary).

However, given that you are working with existing code, there is most probably already a function defined to draw text and it probably only uses a subset of the possible operators. You would probably be better advised to modify that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the i18n issue.  I've updated the question.